# EditText input into array

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, button, android-edittext

I have an input box (EditText1) 
1. that i want to keep adding values and save them to an Array
2.  then when am done, i can click the done button and it can take me to the next screen and I can display the values or call the values of the array.. this is what i have so far 
1. Done Button Works
2. Add more button and storing to array doesn't quite work....HELP PLZ,

Thanks

**EDIT :**
Here is the edited code:

```
private EditText txt1;
public static ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();
String playerlist[];

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    // edittext1 or textview1
    txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
     final String ag = txt1.getText().toString();



        //add more items button
    Button more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view){
            if(txt1.getText().length() != 0){
                                     playerList.add(ag);
                            DisplayToast("Current Players" + playerList);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                    Screen2.class);
             myIntent.putExtra("playerList",playerList);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }

        }});
    }
    //display message 
    private <Strg> String DisplayToast(String ag) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ag, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        return ag;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your array public static in the activity you are currently in.Then you can directly access that array in next activity.

**EDIT :**

As per the scenario you declared in your question,Try this code:
say this is your Screen1.class:

```
private EditText txt1;
public static ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();
String playerlist[];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.screen2);

    // edittext1 or textview1
    txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); 

    //add more items button
    Button more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view){

            String ag=txt1.getText().toString().trim();
            if(ag.length() != 0){
                   playerList.add(ag); 
                   txt1.setText(""); // adds text to arraylist and make edittext blank again
            }
        }
    });

    //press Done button to redirect to next activity
    Button done = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_button);
    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view){

            // start new activity
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                    Screen2.class);             
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

In your Screen2.class,directly access ArrayList like:

```
String s=Screen1.playerList.get(index);// this gives your the string saved in arraylist at index given.
```

I hope,it's clear now!

Comment: i did this first
public class Screen2 extends Activity {
 private EditText txt1;
 String ag;
  
 ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();
 String playerlist[];

Comment: I was telling you to make your array public static.

Comment: i've updated my original code, would that work instead of declaring it as a public static?

Comment: @user1179083: no...because another activity would want access to your array list which is being updated in your first activity.

Comment: i did this, is that right? `public class Screen2 extends Activity {
 private EditText txt1;
 String ag;
 public static ArrayList<String> playerList = new ArrayList<String>();
 String playerlist[];`

Comment: Yes...In this class,you keep adding items to ArrayList and when you press done,just redirect control to next activity.There,you can access this array list using Screen2.playerList

Comment: @user1179083: what problem do you get with this?

Comment: am lost now....let me put up my revised code, it's not showing the array in the toast message now...i don't know if i have done that right...look at my revised code

Comment: ok..please post the updated code in your question under title EDIT: so that we can know better what the problem may be with your code.

Comment: ok ..looking at it now..thanks for your help in advance, i know you don't have to help me and i really appreciate it!!!

Comment: ok it does help...however, in screen3 (not screen2) how do i get it to display the array...do i use a list? textview? or something?

Comment: That's a different issue now.I think,you haven't clear your basics on android yet.please refer listview.That would be better one,I think.Do some work onto that and bring your problem to us if you face any.We can help you for your issues but can't write complete code for you!

Answer (score 0):

While onClick the done button just pass the string array to next activity and get the values of array in next screen and display it..You can pass the string array as below

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                Screen2.class);

    myIntent.putExtra("Stringarray",arrayvalue);
    startActvity(myIntent);
   finish();
```

In Next activity you can get value as

```
        String[] array=getIntent().getExtras().getStringArray("Stringarray");
```

Edit:

```
 for(int i=0;i<array.size;i++)
{
    Toast.makeText(this,array[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG); // here if you have value in array then it will display in toast one by one.
}
```

I think it may help you...

Comment: i've edited my code..to include the string array coding aswell.

Comment: can i display the array in a  toast so i see if they can display first?

Comment: Am using this code, but it takes me to screen1 and i'm not even calling screen1 so i don't know what's going on

Comment: i have this:
`//add more items button
  Button more = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
  more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view){
    if(txt1.getText().length() != 0){
     String ag = "Current Added Players:," +txt1.getText().toString() + txt1.getText().toString() ;
      playerList.add(ag);
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ag,
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
      Screen2.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("Stringarray",playerList);
        `

Comment: You have to start the actvity as startActivity(myIntent); before finish the activity.Check my answer.